# Is it possible to use Ansible ad-hoc command with filter plugins?

Tags: ansible

I'd like to use some custom filters(e.g. `myfilter` in following results). I've checked it works in a playbook but not in an ad-hoc command:

```sh
❯ ansible -m debug -a "var={{ test | myfilter  }}" -e "test=123" local -i localhost
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: No filter named 'myfilter'.. String: {{ test | myfilter  }}"
}
```

I ran above ad-hoc command in the same path where ran the playbook which has `ansible.cfg`:

```sh
❯ cat ansible.cfg
[default]
filter_plugins = path/to/filter_plugins
```

Can I run ad-hoc commands with my custom plugin filters?
Or how could I load the configuration for ad-hoc commands if that was missing?

Answer (score 2):

The ad-hoc `ansible` command will look for your `ansible.cfg` file in the current directory. E.g., if I have in `/home/lars/tmp/ansible` the following structure:

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── filter_plugins
│   ├── myfilter.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       └── myfilter.cpython-310.pyc
├── hosts.yaml
└── playbook.yaml
```

Where `filter_plugins/myfilter.py` contains:

```
def myfilter(v):
    return v.upper()


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {"myfilter": myfilter}
```

And `ansible.cfg` contains:

```
[defaults]
filter_plugins = /home/lars/tmp/ansible/filter_plugins
```

I can run an ad-hoc command that makes use of the custom filter:

```
$ ansible all -i hosts.yaml -m debug -a 'msg="{{\"hello\"|myfilter}}"'
node0 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "HELLO"
}
```

But if I try running that command from any other directory, it will fail:

```
$ cd ..
$ ansible all -i ansible/hosts.yaml -m debug -a 'msg="{{\"hello\"|myfilter}}"'
node0 | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: No filter named 'myfilter'.. String: {{\"hello\"|myfilter}}"
}
```

---

If I provide an explicit path to the configuration file, it works as expected:

```
$ pwd
/home/lars/tmp
$ ANSIBLE_CONFIG=$PWD/ansible/ansible.cfg ansible all -i ansible/hosts.yaml -m debug -a 'msg="{{\"hello\"|myfilter}}"'
node0 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "HELLO"
}
```

Comment: I can see that the problem is from the typo in configuration, the section name 'default' without ending 's', with your answer. Ad-hoc command only works for filter_plugins config in exactly 'defaults' section but playbook is not, also work well with my mispelled configuration, in 'default' section.  It's weird.